# about non-static class in java

Tags: java

My doubt is when I run the following program

```
public class NonStatic
{
  class a
  {
    static  int b;
  }
}
```

The compiler is giving a error that "inner classes cannot have static declarations"

ok,then I made a change instead of "static int b" to "final static int b" its giving

same error but when I wrote "final static int b=10" means with initialization compiler

didn't complain,please can any body explain this what's the concept behind this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my take on this issue.

1. Inner class is defined as a not static member of outer class and hence, it's instance cannot exist without the instance of outer class.
2. The static fields of a class are accessible without creating an instance of that class.
3. Now if you add a static field in the inner class, that means you can access that field without create the instance of inner class BUT according to #1 instance of inner cannot exist without an instance of outer class. So this is the conflict and hence the error.

TO CROSSCHECK : Just declare the inner class static and it will correct the error.

Comment: thanks santosh,then why its working for static int b=10; according to concept it should not?

Comment: @yagnya:  'static int b=10' will give compile error. only 'final static int  b=10'  will work which is as good as any constant.

Answer (score 3):

it is so by design, just see the Java Language Specification: [Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.1.3)

> An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly declared static. [...] Inner classes may not declare static members, unless they are compile-time constant fields (§15.28).

Answer (score 1):

`final static int b=10`
Is interpreted as a constant so compiler can just inline it. Similarly you can have static final constants in interface.

`final static int b` 
Is missing initialization,which is required for final member, so compiler can't quite figure what you want.
Try putting following block right after it out of curiosity:

```
static {
  b=10;
}
```

Although it probably would not work...

Comment: yes its not working..if we wrap the inner class inside the interface it will work

Comment: @yagnya: wrapping in an interface will work, because nested interfaces are always static and all classes defined inside interfaces are static as well. So you've effectively found a complicated way to add the `static` keyword to your class definition.

Answer (score 1):

If a field is static, there is only one copy for the entire class, rather than one copy for each instance of the class
A final field is like a constant: once it has been given a value, it cannot be assigned to again. hence when we r using final we have to assign the value to the variable.
have a look at the following [link](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs368-1/JavaTutorial/NOTES/Java-Classes.html#static)

Answer (score 0):

Its because a final static variable is a constant meaning it can't change at run time, while a static variable is not a constant and can change during runtime.

So in a class static variables aren't allowed in an inner class but the constants(final) are allowed.